# Upgrading node version on a mac

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upgrade my node version on my mac.

I have installed the latest version, but am struggling to find a command that lets me use it.

The active version is v8 and I can't find a command to get my mac to use the updated version.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `nvm`?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman - yes - I've been through the instructions to clear the cache, install and then specify a version - but the node -v check keeps using v8

Comment: Check `which node` to be sure you're using the right one. As a note your "active" one here is listed wrong.

Comment: @tadman - which node returns: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node

Comment: Maybe uninstalling v8 would correct the issue.

Comment: nvm uninstall 8.15.1 returns "command not found"

Comment: You should check your `PATH` as it looks like NVM is promoting that particular `node` version earlier, or something else has. Is a Homebrew package interfering with NVM?

Comment: Ok - thanks. I'll try and find the source of this problem. I have homebrew installed but it gives an error message saying that brew doesn't support macOS 10.15.

Comment: You may need to update Homebrew first, then resolve that, then get back to this. Rabbit holes!

Comment: yep - not working but that's life sometimes